3DS outscale OOS access
I want to create a read/write access limited to a specific OutScale Object Storage bucket.
There is no information in the EIM documentation on how to achieve that.
I set up a bucket with the correct APL and I tried the following EIM Managed Policy
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "oos:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "MYBUCKET"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

It doesn't work.
What would be the correct EIM policy ?
